# IBM Cloud API: How can I get the IAM-id of an IBM ID/user?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud

I am trying to create a new account in my IBM Cloud Enterprise hierarchy by using the IBM Cloud API: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/enterprise-apis/enterprise#create-a-new-account-in-an-enterprise.

It requests to provide the account owner: owner_iam_id (The IAM ID of the account owner, such as IBMid-0123AB). I used an email to create the IBM id, how can I get the IAM ID associated to that user?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IAM id via the IBM Cloud UI or the ibmcloud CLI:

- **UI**

1. Sign into https://cloud.ibm.com/ and click on Manage drop down menu
2. Click on **Access (IAM)**
3. Click on **Users** on left list
4. Click on the user you want to get the IAM id
5. Click on **Details** on top left corner and the IAM id should appear

[image: User details]

- **ibmcloud CLI**

1. Install `jwt-cli` to decode contents of token.
   `$ npm install -g jwt-cli`
2. Use your favorite way to log into ibmcloud CLI, here is one way.
   `$ ibmcloud login --sso`
3. Get the token for your active session.
   `$ ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens`
4. Decode contents of your token (Omit the string Bearer).
   `$ jwt <TOKEN_FROM_STEP_3`

Comment: More information on [tokens issued by IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-tokens)